# PHP MSSQL Server connection issue

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a database of MSSQL server 2005. I can connect to the server via MSSLQL client software (MSSQL Management Studio).
The issue is I cant connect to the server from PHP script using the same credentials. And also all mssql configurations are valid in php and apache.

This is the error I receive:

```
<b>Warning</b>: mssql_connect() 
[Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: eventsearch.db.7340680.hostedresource.com in /home/horizon/public_html/openivite/server.php on line 2]
```

**PHP:**

```
 $this->dblink = mssql_connect(FBSERVER, FBUSER, FBPASSWORD);
```

All credentials are valid and working.

Comment: errors , show us some error log

Comment: show us the code you are trying to connect with

Comment: Are you connecting throw Windows Authentication, More info plz

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  mssql_connect() [<a href='function.mssql-connect'>function.mssql-connect</a>]:

Comment: @Chintoo: edit your question, don't post comments please. And please show PHP code you're using to connect to db

Comment: What is in FBSERVER? Just the server name or an instance too? If so, the instance written with 2 backslashes in the php constant? `server\\instance`

Comment: @Marco, I am not so lazy. FBSERVER have valid server name which i am using in query anylyzer to connect

Comment: It seems like there's information missing from the warning.  That was the *entire text* of the warning / error given?

Comment: I agree with @Crontab - the error would more like this: `<b>Warning</b>: mssql_connect() [<a href='function.mssql-connect'>function.mssql-connect</a>]: Some useful error message`

Comment: Is it a firewall issue between the web server and the SQL server?  "Unable to connect to server" would seem to indicate that the web server can't hit port 1433 on the SQL server.

Comment: @Crontab I can telnet to it, so it seems this is probably not the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your web server running on Windows?  If so, what version of ntwdblib.dll do you have?  See [this help page](http://www.helpspot.com/helpdesk/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=13) for a much more in-depth explanation.

This error is a pain because it's not very descriptive.  I remember the first time I had to wrestle with it (the problem has been around for at least a few years)... but having the correct DLL makes all the difference in the world.

If you're trying to connect from a linux box, then you might consider switching from mod_php to php-cgi (or vice versa) as I've read success stories from that.  But then, I don't remember ever having this problem when connecting a linux web server to a MSSQL box.

Comment: When I print the phpinfo() the mssql library is different there.
Library version : FreeTDS

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found a comment on the PHP manual that did the trick: 
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mssql-connect.php#105132

The issue was a SELinux configuration (On my CentOS box). By default remote connections via php (or any other language run by Apache) are disabled on SElinux enabled machines.

So modifying the policies revoked the block and my php scripts began to work as expected.

the command is:

> sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1

:)